# Refreshing fields when selecting date

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to refresh all other fields in my page, when I change the date from the following calendar :

```
<p:column>
    <h:outputText id="StartTime" value="Start Time:" />
</p:column>
<p:column>
    #{' '}
    <p:calendar id = "StTm" required="false" value="#{visitBean.startingTime}" 
                pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" showButtonPanel="true"/>    
    <p:watermark for="StartTime" value="Enter Time" />
    #{' '}
</p:column>
```

What change or addition should I do in this calendar so that when I change the date from here, the other fields that have to be selected are refreshed to initial value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<p:calendar id = "StTm" required="false" value="#{visitBean.startingTime}" 
            pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" showButtonPanel="true">
  <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="@all" /> </p:calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use ajaxs and use render attribute

```
<p:calendar >
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{}"  render="@form,@ALL"/>
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: what should i call in the listener?

Comment: i do not know your business but you can alert to user the date he selected like this public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Date Selected", format.format(event.getObject())));
    }

Comment: Thanks for the help. But that isnt the issue.
I just want to refresh the fields on date selection, without any ajax call, since i dont want to call any function.